# scheme simple stream-map will not work in SICP example

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, delayed-execution

An excerpt from SICP book,
For the last line given there is problem with scheme code compilation,
As I see it, the functions sqr and shower are both functions of single argument that return a single value. And hence should work.
For the below given code in scheme:

```
(define (stream-car stream)
  (car stream))

(define (stream-cdr stream)
  (force (cdr stream)))

;; cons-stream needs to be a macro

(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ a b) (cons a (delay b))]
    ))

(define the-empty-stream '())

(define stream-null? null?)

;; define stream-for-each
;; run a procedure on each element of stream
(define (stream-for-each proc stream)
  (if (stream-null? stream)
      'done
      (begin (proc (stream-car stream))
             (stream-for-each proc (stream-cdr stream)))))

(define test-stream (cons-stream 2 (cons-stream 3 (cons-stream 4 '()))))

;; displays passed argument but with a newline
(define (display-line x)
  (newline)
  (display x))

(define (display-stream stream)
  (stream-for-each display-line stream))

;; stream map
(define (stream-map proc stream)
  (if (stream-null? stream)
      the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream (proc (stream-car stream))
                   (stream-map proc (stream-cdr stream)))))

(define (sqr x)
  (* x x))

(define (stream-enumerate-interval low hi)
  (if (> low hi)
      '()
      (cons-stream low (stream-enumerate-interval (+ 1 low) hi))))

(define (shower x)
  (display-line x)
  x)

;; this works
(define yyy (stream-map sqr (stream-enumerate-interval 1 10)))


;; reason why below wont work?
;; (define xxx (stream-map shower (stream-enumerate-interval 1 10)))
```

Also as per SICP book, it defines a different version of stream-map that allows procedures that accepts procedures that can take multiple arguments.

I fail to understand the need for a different stream-map and why above stream-map code on the last line won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them work, but since `stream-map` is lazy you won't get them computed in full unless you do something to force it. Eg. lets make `stream->list`:

```
(define (stream->list stream)
  (if (stream-null? stream)
      '()
      (cons (stream-car stream)
            (stream->list (stream-cdr stream)))))

(stream->list yyy)
; ==> (1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)

(stream->list zzz)
; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) (and as a side effect prints then one line at a time)
```

The fact is the actual computation on the rest of the list is never ever done unless you try to access the value. `stream->list` forces the computation of the whole stream so then it gets computed.

Notice that the sicp streams always force the first value regardless. This is a simplification that other stream libraries have fixed so in [SRFI-41](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) you don't have any side effect unless you access the result.

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (srfi :41))

;; nothing is displayed after this expression is evaluated 
(define squares (stream-map (lambda (x) (shower (* x x)))
                            (stream-from 0)))

(stream-car squares)
; ==> 0 (displays "\n0")

(stream->list 4 squares)
; ==> (0 1 4 9) 
; (displayes "\n1\n4\n9" since "0" is already calculated.)
```

Comment: Hmm, I am using geiser with emacs and send .scm buffer to guile REPL started with geiser inside emacs. It opens a Geiser DBG buffer when I uncomment last line i.e. define xxx,

Although opening guile repl in terminal and doing a (load "filename.scm") worked fine..

Comment: Thanks for the SFRI link. Wonderful treatise on streams.

Comment: @chetnashah Your code works without errors in drracket so I guess you might have encountered a bug in your implementation or the emacs interface.